# Weird and flashing characters in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I'm having weird and flashing characters in different Ubuntu windows, such as Terminal, Settings, right button menus and applications such as LibreOffice etc. This has happened several times in the past few weeks (the computer is 2-3 months old) and it disappears when I restart the computer.

This has happens when I'm running computationally intensive custom made scripts in R and/or PERL, but doesn't happen in web pages or third party apps, such as Rstudio or Eclipse.

I tried to change the fonts in the Terminal's preferences, but none seems to work.

[image: Weird and flashing characters in Ubuntu 20.04]

Does anyone have the same problem?

---

Please, find some more information about the system:

- OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
- OS-type: 64-bit
- Kernel Version: 5.13.0-37-generic
- GNOME Version: 3.36.8
- Windowing System: X11
- Graphics: NV106
- Processor: AMD® Ryzen 9 5950x 16-core processor × 32
- Motherboard: MSI B550M-A PRO (MS-7C96)
- Output of `lspci | grep VGA`:

  ```
  2b:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 730] (rev a1)
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is here, but you might be able to avoid restarting your computer when that happens by restarting GNOME Shell. You can do that by pressing `Alt`+`F2`, entering "r", and pressing `Enter`.

Comment: Thanks for adding the requested info, though next time, please try to [edit] your question and add the info there instead of adding it in a comment. You see, you don't have many formatting options in the comments, which makes the text there hard to read or even totally unreadable if it is a long command output. This time I added the info for you from your comment to the question. Also have a look at the various [formatting options](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) so you can make your posts in the future prettier, more readable, and increasing the chances of getting an answer. Thanks! :)